# Can't transpose array. Error 5 (Invalid procedure or argument)

Tags: arrays, vba, transpose

I have some problems with array transpose. 
It gives me an Error 5 (Invalid procedure or argument) on this line

```
Range = Application.Transpose(DataArr)
```

1) The array is passed to this sub from other sub.
2) This sub is called from two different subs.

```
Sub ArrToSheet(Report As String, DataArr As Variant)
....
Range = Application.Transpose(DataArr)
```

When it called from the first sub it works correctly. But when I try to call it from another sub I get an error.
Arrays that I passing to this sub a mostly identical (sometimes different dimensions size).

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Range is a Range Object right? Are you sure what you're passing to DataArr is an array? What is the size? Transpose have limitations in handling large arrays.

Comment: Yes, Range is a Range object.

Comment: And the answer to the other 2 questions?

Comment: Yes I am sure that I am passing an array because when I try to write DataArr without transposing it's ok. The size is about 100 in both dimensions

Comment: Hmmm... there should be no problem. The line with the Transpose is specifically what's causing the error?

Comment: Finaly I discovered that there was no problem in transposing. The problem was in the array more precisely I made а mistake in the algorithm of its filling. Аfter I rewrote the algorithm all began to work.

Comment: That's what I thought as well :) Good thing you fix it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finaly I discovered that there was no problem in transposing. The problem was in the array more precisely I made а mistake in the algorithm of its filling. Аfter I rewrote the algorithm all began to work.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Could you elaborate on what the "mistake" was that you made?